# Snow Leopard - PHP 5.3.1 installed... but no PEAR?

Tags: php, osx-snow-leopard, pear

I've been trying to do some PHP work on my snow leopard machine.. but I've found issues when I need to use PEAR packages (as symfony handles its php plugins with PEAR).

I've found some references that state that snow leopard includes PEAR.. but how come I cant find it?!

Could someone confirm this.. if if so, where is my pear?

Answer (score 3):

In OSX Snow Leopard and later pear isn't installed by default.  The installer is already available to you though.

```
sudo php /usr/lib/php/install-pear-nozlib.phar
pear config-set php_ini /private/etc/php.ini
pecl config-set php_ini /private/etc/php.ini
sudo pear upgrade-all
```

Answer (score 0):

**/usr/bin/pear**

I ran `which pear`  from the command line.

Answer (score 0):

```
which pear 
/usr/local/bin/pear
```

if which doesn't work try `locate pear` which will search your machine, if a result is returned you need to update you .bash_profile (in your home directory) to include pear (normally the parent directory) eg.

```
export PATH="/usr/local/bin:$PATH"
```

If you can't locate pear on your system, use terminal to get it :

```
curl http://pear.php.net/go-pear > go-pear.php
sudo php -q go-pear.php
```

All the options can be left at default except install directory which you need to set. Mine is `/usr/local` but other locations such as `/opt/local` will be fine (as long as the path is in your bash profile...